# Background image that shows when list is empty in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image, list

How would I display a `backgroundImage` on a `List` when the `List` is empty?

At the moment the list is populated when items are dropped inside after a drag-and-drop but I would prefer a solution that checks for any change to the data to determine if the list is empty.

The `List` inherits a `backgroundImage` from its `ScrollControlBase` but what would be the best way to make it appear when the list is empty and disappear when an item is added.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past, I've done it with states for a component. Quick and dirty example would be something like this in your custom component:

`<mx:List currentState="{(listItemsDataProvider.length > 0) ? 'HasItemsState' : 'NoItemsState'}">`

`// anything else you need`

`</mx:List>`

and of course creating those states in the component, with the NoItemsStates changing the background image, or if your component is a container, like a `Canvas`, then you can have the state not display the `List` at all.

Comment: I've based my solution on that, it's pretty simple, although I directly used backgroundImage="{(listItemsDataProvider.length > 0) ? null : 'image.png'}" but I'll definitely look at states.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable] public var listItems:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            private function removeAllItemsFromList():void
            {
                this.listItems.removeAll();
                backgroundCheck()
            }

            private function addItemToList():void
            {
                this.listItems.addItem({data:null,label:"test"});
                backgroundCheck()
            }

            private function backgroundCheck():void
            {
                if(this.listItems.length>0)
                {
                    this.myList.setStyle("backgroundImage", null)
                }
                else
                {
                    this.myList.setStyle("backgroundImage", "me.png")
                }               
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:List id="myList" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundImage="me.png" dataProvider="{this.listItems}"/>
        <mx:HBox width="100%">
            <mx:Button id="addItemButton" click="addItemToList()" label="add item"/>
            <mx:Button id="removeItemsButton" click="removeAllItemsFromList()" label="remove all items"/>
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

This is how I would approach it, checking the dataProvider length. In your case you'd do so when the drop is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the List control and override updateDisplayList().  Draw the backgroundImage if dataProvider.length == 0 else call super.updateDisplayList() to get normal List behavior. This will make the new List control easy to reuse if you need to.

Comment: I think it's really the best way to do it but not necessarily the easiest. This way your component still extends from List and can be treated exactly like a List, instead of having to wrap it with a Canvas or another Container.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same property, set the image to null when you have some data. You may take a look at custom `ItemRenderers` as well.